# want to access sharepoint remotely for using sharepoint api

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, virtualization, remote-desktop, remote-access

We have a sharepoint server 2010 installed on a machine(say server A) which we can access remotely.

Till now we were using sharepoint webservices to communicate with sharepoint.

But now we want to use sharepoint.dll to code.

i read somewhere that we need to coding on the same machine on which the sharepoint server is installed(Server A in this case).  Is this correct , pls correct me if i am wrong?

Here starts the problem , We can not access the server physically, we have only remote access( using remote desktop means only 2 connection at a time).

We are a team of 5 people needs to code simutaneously, we should i do for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct, the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is the server object model, which only can be accessed when you are connected to the server.

There is a client object model aswell, which allows your code to be executed remotely. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx However this is not the solution you are looking for.

Each of your team members needs to install SharePoint in an virtual environment (i'd recommend using VMware) on your developer pc/laptop. (Obviously you will install it only once and then copy the VWware disk).

If you never installed a Windows/SharePoint server yourself, get the admin who installed Server A to do it, because it can be quite tricky. Heres a guide if you want to try yourself: http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2009/11/installing-sharepoint-2010-windows-2008.html

Answer (score 0):

This may be getting to you too late, but... just in case.
I would strongly suggest you to think twice before trying this, but you'll see this may get to help you.
I was very concerned about remote development when I first started working with SP, but then I convinced the PM to have local environments and I didn't need to complete my research.

REMOTE CODING:
However, I started having to bring some work to home and needed to connect remotely to my PC at work, so I eventually got sick bored of latency and connected my laptop's VS2010 (ultimate) to my employeer TFS and got latest version. I have to remark I run win 7 64 bits.
Of course when I tried to compile the solution my machine started complaning because it didn't have an idea what that Sharepoint.dll was supposed to be.
That's when I connected remotelly to my work-pc and got from the GAC a that dll. (see here how to extract a dll from GAC: http://metahat.blogspot.com/2008/08/copy-extract-dll-from-gac.html). Then I copied that to my machine and installed it in my own GAC (gacutil -I "C:[PathToBinDirectoryInVSProject]\gac.dll").
I had to do it a few times since our app does some crazy things and had pretty much to depend on. Normally you'll be told what is missing and you can go in msdn and see what assembly contains it.
Ok, after all that I got to compile it and it worked like a charm.

DEPLOY AND TEST
That can help you coding. Now, from my past shared-Websphere-appserver experiences I can bet you sinchronizing a team to deploy in one app server will be a headache. Think that some of you will be able to compile but do not run.
Since SP has dlls inside the GAC, having different versions of your app running in different web apps is something quite complicated. (I prefeer not to discuss if it is possible, but if my idea is possible, then it is at least very complex in terms of configuration management)
Of course you can share a folder at your server, compile, copy the pkg dlls to the shared folder, then use the trick of drag and drop to move (some of) them to the GAC and finally iis reset. (I used to have a script to do it all but the drag and drop)

I simply decided to commit (perhaps in a different branch) and then deploy from the remote machine. But mainly I decided to code from my laptop all but specific SP view components, therefore I was able to simply validate that all by running my Unit tests without the SP

DEBUG
In adition, If this all didn't got you affraid enought of even trying, then you can find in here some instructions about how to get to debug remotelly your SP2010
http://techblog.hk.agenda-asia.com/2010/10/29/create-sharepoint-project-without-install-sharepoint-server/

Well, that's all i know about shrimp. :p (ment I wrote too much)